# Is it of any consequence how many cryo trays you save from Kharak?

Tags: homeworld, homeworld-remastered-collection

In the third mission of Homeworld Remastered, **Return To Kharak**, upon our appearance, a number of frigates are attacking the cryo trays containing the remaining people from our planet.

In our second attempt, we were still only able to salvage five of the six cryo trays. Is it of any consequence (besides our anguish at having lost 100.000 people) for the game progress, how many of the cryo trays have been rescued?

I.e. does saving all six trays perhaps give you bonus resources, research or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I recall, there are no bonuses for saving more than the needed amount of trays. Other than the emotional implications and dialogue.

A similar event happens in Homeworld 2 where you are saving crew ships where you are indeed rewarded for saving more than the required with elite versions of strike craft.